# How to document @typedef as @memberof a @namespace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I should point out that I am using VSCode as my IDE

**Question**

How do I document a `@typedef` such that it is a member of a `@namespace`? (I am open to `@module` or other JSDoc tags to achieve this, but seemed to be getting closest with this approach)

I am working on a React project and have my domain objects represented as entities

**folder structure**

```
- entities/
  - group/
    - group-actions.js
    - group-model.js
    - group-reducer.js
    - group-selectors.js
    - group-service.js
    - index.js
```

**index.js**

```
import Actions from './group-actions';
import Model from './group-model';
import reducer from './group-reducer';
import Selectors from './group-selectors';
import Service from './group-service';

/**
 * GroupNamespace
 * @namespace Group
 */
const Group = {
  Actions,
  Model,
  reducer,
  Selectors,
  Service,
};

/**
 * Group
 * @typedef {Object} GroupInstance
 * @memberof Group
 * @property {Object[]} members
 * @property {Object} permissions
 */

export default Group;
```

Now, I would like to define a React component that receives a `GroupInstance` as a prop

[image]

I would expect to see `members` in that intellisense dropdown, but do not.

Now, if I change the `@property` definition to `@property {Group} group` I do get intellisense on the @namespace

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Documentation for @typedef is found at https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html#syntax.

I've found you have two options:

Option 1 is to use `@typedef` and append with data type, and include separate `@name` and `@memberOf`
 Option 1 Example:

```
/**
* Your description goes here.
* @typedef {type}
* @memberOf module:your/module
* @name yourTypedefName
*/
```

Option 2 is to omit `@name` and `@memberOf`, and define full path with data type in `@typedef` 
 - https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html
 Option 2 example

```
/**
 * Your description goes here.
 * @typedef {Object} module:your/module.yourTypedefName
 */
```

Also, you can put @type as separate line as well with the type, then for Option 1, your line with @typedef will just have @typedef on it.